# Trying to find a book with Tiny Aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

This book is about a guy who one day starts hearing voices in his head. The voices are clueless as to their surroundings; they don't know what anything is and are quite confused about this world (they don't even know what hands are). The main character freaks out at first, but when he realizes he isn't getting rid of them he starts teaching them about the world. At first there are just a few voices, but as time goes on more and more voices join in. The main character is somehow able to track down these voices and goes into the middle of the woods only to find a ship with tiny aliens who are building said ship. They are taking the information that the main character is teaching them to go back to their mothership so they can invade Earth.

Other things I know: This book was not written by Stephen King, but the writer is a man. There is only one real character throughout the book, who is a white male (I think the FBI might show up at the end though). When the aliens speak, the font changes. There is also quite a bit of cussing, from what I remember.

The Aliens would be able to speak back and forth to each other and the conversation would kind of be like this: "Whats that glowing thing up there? What is that?" "Oh I don't know. Hey what is he doing with his hands?" "I don't know what are hands?" That's just to give an example of the conversations they would have to learn information.

I found this book in a library a few years ago, and I want to say it was published between 1990-2010, something like that.

I know it isn't *The Lives of Tao* and I know it's not *TommyKnockers*.

Edit- I have stopped searching for a bit, but I have started up for a bit. I found a book that is eerily similar, but it isn't quite it. The book is "Corpus Earthling" by Louis Charbonneau. I don't know if this information is helpful, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.